# Node JS: Cannot get/

Tags: node.js, get

I know there are already different variations of the same question, however, mine is little different. I am getting this error cannot get/, this is my node js code

```
// set up ======================================================================
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();                        // create our app w/ express
var mongoose = require('mongoose');                 // mongoose for mongodb
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;                // set the port
//var database = require('./config/database');          // load the database config
var morgan = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var io = require('socket.io');
var messageId = {};
    http = require('http'),
    server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
       res.writeHead(200,{'content-type':'text/plain'});
        res.write("Sever On");
        res.end();
    }),
    io = io.listen(server);
// configuration ===============================================================
//mongoose.connect(database.localUrl);  // Connect to local MongoDB instance. A remoteUrl is also available (modulus.io)

//app.use(express.static('./public'));      // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
//app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended': 'true'})); // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
//app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parse application/json
//app.use(bodyParser.json({type: 'application/vnd.api+json'})); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
//app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override')); // override with the X-HTTP-Method-Override header in the request


// routes ======================================================================
//require('./app/routes.js')(app);

// listen (start app with node server.js) ======================================
app.listen(port);
console.log("App listening on port " + port);
```

My Package.json

```
{
  "name": "node-todo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Simple todo application.",
  "main": "server.js",
  "author": "Scotch",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "mongoose": "4.10.8",
    "express": "^4.10.8",
    "method-override": "^2.3.10",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

As you might have noticed, I am just trying to create a response using http.createServer().
Please let me know what did I do wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code just creates the server -

```
server = http.createServer();
```

But to send any response to client you must first listen to request i.e. create routes -

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('blah');
}
```

Other stuff you have written correctly I guess. I hope it fixes your problem.

Comment: **There is no need to create a server @Rahul.** In this program, he is creating two servers. You can run this program without `server = http.createServer();` as `var app = express()` itself creates one server and express handles the stuff under the hoods. Above two lines in your answer have no relationship with each other. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You're right if your goal is just to create a node.js server. However, to listen both node.js requests and socket events on the same protocol, you should create HTTP server.

Comment: yeah but you can pass express app object in the initilization `var app = express(); var server = require('http').Server(app); var io = require('socket.io')(server);` so it will use same sever instance of express.

Comment: Yep! .Server() and .createServer() are same things.

Answer (score 0):

There are two servers created in your script. You only need to create any one of them.

1. Core HTTP server with `http.createServer()` but you haven't bound any port to it.
2. You have created an express server(`var app = express();  app.listen(port);`). Here you provided port but haven't provided any routing information.

Here is what you can do :

**1. If you want to use core HTTP server**

replace your sever initilization with

```
server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200,{'content-type':'text/plain'});
    res.write("Sever On");
    res.end();
}).listen(port),
```

**2. If you want to use express**

Add root route

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('hello world')
})
```

before `app.listen(port);`